# Functional way of conditional filtering and sorting in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to sort and/or filter a sequence. Basically something like this:

```
var result = getReallyLongSeq() // returns Seq[SomeClass]

if (doFilter) {
  result = result.filter( ... )
}

if (doSort) {
  result = result.sortWith( ... )
}
```

Now, this is an obviously valid approach, but is there a more functional way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without library support, you can roll out your own *Boolean Reader Monad*.

This is *functional, pure and configurable*.

**Boolean Reader**

```
case class BoolConf[A](run: Boolean => A) {
    def apply(b: Boolean) = run(b)
    def map[B](f: A => B): BoolConf[B] = BoolConf(b => f(run(b)))
    def flatMap[B](f: A => BoolConf[B]): BoolConf[B] = BoolConf(b => f(run(b))(b))
}
```

Here we made a wrapper for a `Boolean => A` that allows monadic composition, and it's probably already implemented in some library, like [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz).

We're only interested in the `run` method, for this case, but you can get interested in other opportunities.

**Configured filter & sort**

Then we wrap our filter and sort check with the `Reader`

```
val mFilter: Seq[SomeClass] => BoolConf[Seq[SomeClass]] = seq => BoolConf(if(_) seq.filter(...) else seq)
val mSort: Seq[SomeClass] => BoolConf[Seq[SomeClass]] = seq => BoolConf(if(_) seq.sortWith(...) else seq)
```

**Lifting**

Now, to *compose* these functions, since the output is no more a simple `Seq`, we need to *lift* one of them to work within a `BoolConf`

```
def lift2Bool[A, B]: (A => B) => (BoolConf[A] => BoolConf[B]) =
    fun => cfg => BoolConf(bool => fun(cfg(bool)))
```

Now we're able to convert any function from `A => B` to a *lifted* function from `BoolConf[A] => BoolConf[B]`

**Composing**

Now we can compose functionally:

```
val filterAndSort = lift2Bool(mSort) compose mFilter
//or the equivalent
val filterAndSort = mFilter andThen lift2Bool(mSort)
//applies as in filterAndSort(<sequence>)(<do filter>)(<do sort>)
```

---

**There's more**

We can also create a generic "builder" for our `mFilter` and `mSort`

```
val configFilter[SomeClass]: (SomeClass => Boolean) => Seq[MyClass] => BoolConf[Seq[SomeClass]] = 
    filterer => seq => BoolConf(if(_) seq.filter(filterer))
```

You can "sort" the sorting equivalent by yourself

*Thanks are due to Runar for the inspiration*

Answer (score 4):

Whether it's more readable or not is open to debate. It is a bit inefficient but it's also purely functional. This approach is also easily extended and rather maintainable.

```
val f: Seq[SomeClass] => Seq[SomeClass] = if(doFilter) _.filter(...) else identity
val s: Seq[SomeClass] => Seq[SomeClass] = if(doSort) _.sortWith(...) else identity
(s compose f)(result)
```

You can also write the following, which is more like the code in the OP. It's also slightly more efficient (but less generic).

```
val filtered = if(doFilter) result.filter(...) else result
if(doSort) filtered.sortWith(...) else filtered
```

---

#### Discussion based on comments

If for some reasons you prefer to use curried functions for the first example  (as mentioned in the comments), you can write the following:

```
def fc(df: Boolean)(xs: Seq[SomeClass]) = if(df) _.filter(...) else identity
def sc(ds: Boolean)(xs: Seq[SomeClass]) = if(ds) _.sortWith(...) else identity
(sc(doSort) compose fc(doFilter))(result)
```

But then you might further write it like this and end up in nearly the same thing as given in the first example:

```
def fc(df: Boolean)(xs: Seq[SomeClass]) = if(df) _.filter(...) else identity
def sc(ds: Boolean)(xs: Seq[SomeClass]) = if(ds) _.sortWith(...) else identity
val f = fc(doFilter)
val s = sc(doSort)
(s compose f)(result)
```

Comment: actually it's not purely functional, because `f` and `s` both take external state into account, so both of them yield different results depending on the value of `doFilter` and `doSort`. If you want it to be purely functional, you have to add a curried parameter to both of them, stating whether to use the function itself, or identity.

Comment: @drexin That can be purely functional. It's called a closure. If `doFilter` and `doSort` are mutable vars, then no, this isn't functional. But if they're immutable and depend only on global constants or immutable arguments to some outer scope, then this is indeed a functional approach, which you will find quite commonly used in languages such as Haskell that don't allow impure definitions.

Comment: Okay, sorry. This might, or might not be pure. But from the posting itself, it is not clear, where doFilter and doSort come from. As long as this is the case, I would consider this potentially impure.

Comment: @drexin Look at what I have added. Making the functions curried actually changes nothing at all about purity of code.

Comment: Yes it does. If `doSort` for example was a `var`, `s` would not be referentially transparent, `sc` is.

Comment: @drexin But all I did was extract the expression `sc(doSort)` and named it `s`. Does this transformation introduce impurity? You always have to use `doSort` some way or the other, as the OP required. I agree with you that the given code might not be pure, depending on the unknown origin of some inputs. But I think you cannot improve anything by using currying.

Comment: Yes, but in the first case, it gets pulled in from the outer context. As long as you cannot guarantee, that it is a `val`, it could change over time and thus affect the behaviour of `s`

Comment: @drexin So can we agree upon this: In the curried version, you are able to write a portion of the code in a pure way (well, ignore the `...`s). But the complete code block, which solves the requested task can never be made pure, no matter what you do, depending on the nature of some of the used expressions. In particular if you go for a one-liner (which some functional languages favor) it will never be pure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18577/discussion-between-drexin-and-ziggystar)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scalaz oparator `|>`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Identity.scala#L58) or define your own:

```
class PipedObject[T](value: T)
{
    def |>[R](f: T => R) = f(value)
}

implicit def toPiped[T](value: T) =  new PipedObject[T](value)

(result |> (r => if (doFilter) r.filter(...) else r) 
        |> (r => if (doSort) r.sortWith(...) else r))
```